# Update column value of the csv file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-science, computer-science

My question is:
Once the customer selects the hotel, ask him the give feedback for the same and
update the rating.csv file as per the data received.And how i update that given feed back to these file.

This is what I tried so far:

```
h_id=str(input("Enter Hotel_Id:"))
with open("rating.csv", "r") as fb:
    csvreader = csv.reader(fb, delimiter=",")
    for row in csvreader:
        if h_id in row[0]:
           print("Hotel Booked Sucessfully")
           f_back=float(input("Please Give Feedback of Hotel you selected outoff 5:"))
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is really unclear, can you improve it please?

Comment: I have update the question.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see what you want to do. What did you try so far? Can you post some code?

Comment: Bro, I have paste ma code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
import pandas as pd

#read the hotels table
hotels = pd.read_csv("rating.csv")

h_id=str(input("Enter Hotel_Id:"))
f_back=float(input("Please Give Feedback of Hotel you selected outoff 5:"))

hotels.loc[hotels.Hotel == h_id,"no_of_feedback" ] = hotels.loc[hotels.Hotel == h_id,"no_of_feedback" ]+1
hotels.loc[hotels.Hotel == h_id,"Feedback" ] = f_back

#store updated table
hotels.to_csv("rating.csv")
```